# How to display thumbnails in article style using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have 3 images which I need to display this way:
[image]

I tried to make it using simplest way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <img src="/image/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="/image/2.jpg"><br /><br />
        <img src="/image/2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

But there is a problem with sizing: images are uploaded by user so all of them can have different sizes and proportions (so image can be a square instead of rectangle). Also I need to limit max-height of the row because images can have up to 1024px height.

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the end results can the image be of fixed size ? Or should that be variable size ?

Comment: @SoorajChandran I can limit maximum width/height of the images, but can't change proportions, so fixed size is possible only by one dimension.

Comment: What about using **img-responsive** class for images from bootstrap?

Comment: Best solution is to use divs inside these columns with fixed height and the image as background image, this way you can use `background-size: cover` so they will always align properly.